# How do I stop phantom Documents redirection?

Tags: network-share

At one point there was a GPO forcing our Documents to a specific remote drive.  That's been revoked quite some time ago.  However, I have 3 specific application document folders that are magically regenerating on that old share.  Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and SQL Server Management Studio (based on Visual Studio).  Is there some magic key that can be changed to reset those specific applications to NOT still create a documents area on that old share anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere there was a server I had not yet logged into so that it could get the new GPO.  It was still trying to put things up there in the background even though I wasn't logged in.